# Refresh page repeat database transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-refresh

I have over 30 aspx pages, i have discovered a problem recently that if i did any kind of database transaction like insert, update, delete and then after the transaction is complete i pressed F5 or refreshed the page in anyway the same is transaction occur.

I searched for a solution but all i could found is that i have to check for viewstate on each button which is impossible, cause that means there will be a lot of work. There got to be generic solution, please help me in this problem.

Edit:

Here is the code on one of the buttons which change a value in data base to either true or false:

```
 protected void btn_Publish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(hf_Published.Value.ToString())))
    {
        publish(false);
    }
    else
    {
        publish(true);

    }

}
```

After the execution of the code if refreshed the page the same code is executed, i noticed that since a break point was placed on this method.

Comment: Maybe if you posted your code someone can help you. This way we can only assume.

Comment: Did you try Post-Redirect-Get pattern? Explain more or provide code

Comment: I agree with @Bojan.  This is just too vague, answers will have to make too many assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. I used this in several project and working successfully.

```
 public bool IsRefreshed
    {
        get
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(Session["RefreshTimeStamp"]) == Convert.ToString(ViewState["RefreshTimeStamp"]))
            {
                Session["RefreshTimeStamp"] = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }




protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        ViewState["RefreshTimeStamp"] = Session["RefreshTimeStamp"];
    }



protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {  

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["RefreshTimeStamp"] = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Comment: Add one cs file in appcode and put this method in that. after that inherit this in your webpage.

Comment: So i all i have to do is to inherit this class in my page, don't i have to do any kind of checking on each button event ?

Comment: I was able to run the code and it worked good with only one minor problem, when the page is refreshed the old content of the page is reloaded, is there anyway to make the the view-state as it is and not to put the old one back.

Comment: please check your onload event. I think you are missing something

Answer (score 2):

There IS a generic solution, used for years by thousands of developers.

And the solution is: each time you perform an intrusive process at the server (insert/update/delete) you don't just render the page but rather you redirect the response with 302 to a **fresh** page with "your transaction succeeded" message.

This way, pressing the F5 will just refresh this message page, not the original page which triggers the transaction.

It is up to you whether or not this is directly applicable in your scenario.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue you could check the following:

> 1. Disable the submit button when necessary
> 2. Add some validation to your code and check for double entries
> 3. Redirect the user to another page after submit

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a real 'transaction' like payments etc. (which others already explained, do redirect etc.),
***You could also try defining caching on your pages that interact with the Db or are bottlenecks*** for your app.
If you wanna have always live info (and it's that 'alive' type of app) then no luck with that solution (but even then), but usually, you can put some reasonable time expiration on how 'fresh' you want your data to be.
[Caching ASP.NET Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk.aspx)